# Could not decide the ways and values to set as primary-id

Tags: database, database-design, primary-key

I have a bunch of table say `Customers` `Products`  `Orders`. I am unable to clearly decide the ways and values to set as primary-id.

I thought of following ways:

1)At first of assigning them using sequence but either they limited or more likely the id's value may not give the information on which table it belongs to (this is just my personal requirement).

2)Using timestamp but I could not use it for all the tables (as all id's would look similar)

3)Using anything (sequence or timestamp) but appending initial digit that would help to uniquely identify which table it belongs to.

or could you suggest any other better approach for this project or generally for any other project.

Answer (score 2):

Do you understand the business process requirements associated with each of these keys? For example your customers may need to search for product identifiers or even read them over the phone, in which case a compact user-friendly coding scheme (e.g. alphanumeric) could be important. If ordering is done online then you might want to use random/hashed order numbers as a layer of protection against spoofing. Customer identifiers may be quite different things depending on the channel and the type of customer (online vs in-person; consumer vs corporate).

Other than your specific business needs the general rules for designing keys are: Simplicity, Stability, Familiarity. Timestamps would be a bizarre and useless choice of key unless you really did need to identify unique periods of time.

Comment: I like your point, though I'm a big enemy of showing identifiers. If the user needs to read it, I would have created two columns. When you do that sometimes the user asks for "a button to change it".

Comment: @The Impaler, If users can't see identifiers then they won't be able to identify things accurately or use the information reliably in the real world. A table can have several keys but at least one of them ought to be visible to users.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to clearly identify which value belongs to which table? That sounds like an *intelligent code* **used and abused** during the 70s and 80s. Please don't use those.

I normally use just a `bigint generated always as identity`. Simple and effective.

A **primary key** value is just a value that identifies the row in the table. Who cares what exact value it has? As long as it's a unique value, you are good. Now, it doesn't matter if, for example, you find the value `10` on all three tables. They will identify different rows anyway, since each one belongs to a separate table.

Also, it's not a good idea to use a unique sequence to insert on all tables. I've seen this one. This can create bottlenecks on some databases, when inserting too many rows at once.